# Track Pardot Form submissions through Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, pardot

I have some Pardot forms embedded on my website and I want to setup the submissions to be tracked in Google Tag Manager. The form submissions redirects the user to an external page outside of the main domain which I don't have access to install tracking pixels.

What is the best practice method to setup these forms so that they track accurately through Tag Manager?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the submission? Or inspect the submit button? If this links out you may be able to use GTMs native link clicks tracking

Comment: Hi Jessie, I think I've been able to resolve my issue by adding an additional class to the button within the Pardot Layout Template.

Comment: That’s great, just ensure to make a custom variable to checks all required fields are filled and returns true. Add the variable as true to the condition of your click classes trigger as if you don’t some form failed will be tracked

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Jesse. How do I go about creating a custom variable to check if all required fields are filled and returns true?

Comment: If you can share a link to the form I can review this and write it with instructions as it’s hard to choose the right method without seeing it. However I would define the innerText or Value of a selected element as variable and write an if x && y != “” then return true. Once this is done you can add a condition in the trigger set up and select the variable and equals true